# HTMLImageElement: Track changes on 'src' property while it's not yet attached

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to track changes that are made to the src property of an [HTMLImageElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#htmlimageelement) while it is not yet attached to the document. My goal is to modify the image URL to force the usage of a certain proxy server using an inserted script. The scripts that use the Image object mainly for preloading are external (3rd party) ones, so I cannot just search & replace any occurence of `instance.src = value` to anything else. I can control the document the scripts are embedded in, but cannot control the scripts themselves.

I already tried to define getter/setter on the Image element

```
Object.defineProperty(
  Image.prototype,
  "src",
  { get : function(){...}, set : function(val){...}}
);
```

But this does not seem to have any effect at all. When creating a new Image just like

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "foo.png";
alert(img.src);
```

neither the setter nor the getter is called.

Do you have any idea what else I might try to get notified when the src property is modified without modifying the original source where the property is set?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all, I wouldn't mess with the built-in prototypes. Second of all, `src` is a property of an Image object, therefore it's created in the constructor. So, rather than trying to overwrite the src, add your methods to the prototype and make them interact with `this.src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I retested my previous answer with your example code - no dice. So, I'll go with Andrei's suggestion instead - don't do this :P Instead, work with methods attached to the prototype through more "conventional" means:

```
Image.prototype.setSrc = function(src) {
    // your code affecting this.src
    // from what I can tell in your use-case, you only need this setter
};

Image.prototype.getImage = function() {
    // but, in case you want to do anything before getting the image
    // you can call this method
};

var img = new Image();
img.setSrc("foo.png");

// snip

document.body.appendChild(img.getImage());
```

Comment: Sorry, but it seems my question was ambiguously. As it should work as a general solution and uses 3rd party code I cannot modify the original source at all, and therefore cannot introduce another property.

Comment: That is...odd. Can you not extend the third party code to do what you need instead? It seems that attempting to modify a core part of JS is `Bad Idea` - especially considering that such a solution may not be supported in all browsers or in the same way. I would be very careful and cautious with your intended route, and I would highly suggest reevaluating your path to see if you can't find a way to extend the 3rd party code.